# How to proxy net-sftp?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, ssh, net-ssh, net-sftp

I'm using `net-sftp` which relies on the `net-ssh` gem.

I'm trying to connect to a remote log service via SFTP, and it requires IP whitelisting. All my current servers have dynamic IPs.

I'm trying to set up a static, secure, proxy server in Google Cloud. I don't really understand all the differences between all the types of proxying, but net-ssh appears to support...

- socks4
- socks5
- 'jump' proxy

I looked into setting up a socks5 proxy with Dante but it appears a bit overkill just to relay the SFTP connection through it, not to mention I think it sends passwords in plain text.

How would I go about proxying net-sftp through some server in the easiest way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to setup a Jump-host server that can reach the target servers and then connecting to the target server by letting the Jump-host server proxy your connection through.

SSH makes it trivially easy:

ssh -J user@jump-host myuser@target-host

In your .ssh/config you can do the following:

```
### First jump-host. Directly reachable
Host jump-host
  HostName jum-phost.example.org

### Host to jump to via jump-host.example.org
Host target-host
  HostName target-host.example.org
  ProxyJump  jump-host
```

This will allow you to use net-ssh as usual. If you dont want to change the config file then you will have to [use](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/net-ssh/Net/SSH/Proxy/Jump) `'net/ssh/proxy/jump'`:

```
require 'net/ssh/proxy/jump'

proxy = Net::SSH::Proxy::Jump.new('user@proxy')
Net::SSH.start('host', 'user', :proxy => proxy) do |ssh|
  ...
end
```

See this [article](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SSH_jump_host) for more info on Jump Hosts.

Comment: Awesome, this is very helpful. I have one fast question... while I was waiting for this to be answered I already got a socks5 server running with Dante. Do you think a "jump host" is more secure? I have to connect to this logging service and the whole point is so my SFTP can have a static IP. I have configured dante according to this https://serverfault.com/questions/986024/is-my-dante-socks5-configuration-secure

Comment: I think they are on equal footing. You could also look into just setting up a VPN tunnel and not worry about any of this. VPN is a more secure and robust approach.

Comment: Do you think net-ssh supports that? a VPN tunnel

Comment: I suppose a better question is, how would I start researching how to do this? Many google searches yield general VPN browsing information.

Comment: For beginners I recommend using [SoftEther VPN Tutorials](https://www.softether.org/4-docs/2-howto). Softether VPN is very easy to work with and supports multiple protocols. However, if you are connecting an on-prem data center to Google Cloud you should check [GCP VPN Interop Guides](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/how-to/interop-guides).

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate the added info